# Export big data from ORACLE DB to bcp file

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle, bcp

Helo,

I have got ORACLE DB table with over 200M records and need migrate this to MSSQL. This process is repeated once a month and should be done +-over night. Fastest method seemed to be using bpc utils.

I tried to create bcp file using C# code, but when run a query to get data always end with exhausted DB temp space, which cannot be raised. When I split this single query with offset and fetch, I must add rownumber. This takes also a lot of time because of sorting.

Next solution could be direct export from oracle SQL developer with delimited columns to create csv file or bcp file, but some errors with encoding appeared. This is quite boring also this manual export takes about 1/3 of day.

My question is, is there any solution to create bpc file using C# in any normal time or any other way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: SSIS 2019 with Microsoft connector for Oracle

Comment: Ok, thank you, do you have any useful link how to use it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connector?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: You may also try [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) option to skip intermediate software and use direct connection to Oracle data source. And if the source table is partitioned (I hope it is a case for a table with 200M rows) you may "parallelize" an access using separate query for each partition (regardless of the solution for data movement)